# Can I buy an iPhone 5C in the US and use it in Ireland?

Tags: unlock, iphone

I'm going to New York soon, and the iPhone 5C is just $99 USD. I am wondering if  an Irish SIM work or if I would have to get it unlocked?

Comment: Would you link to the exact model you are considering buying? The unlocked 5c is your safest bet, and you'll discover that costs much more for several reasons.

Comment: Most likely if you see a $99 iPhone 5C it includes a 2 year service agreement with a carrier.

Answer (score 1):

When you buy an iPhone in America for $99 it's probably a SIM-lock together with an subscription. [Here](http://www.apple.com/iphone-5c/specs/) you can find the different iPhone 5S models. Search on the internet which Cellular frequencies are used by your provider, and then compare on the site I gave you which models you can use. Mostly the $99 models are locked for AT&T, Verizon,... providers only. So when buying an iPhone in America, make sure you check to model nr on the back of the package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your iPhone internationally. Just make sure you get one without sim lock (safest bet is an apple store) 
It will cost you more than 99$ (That's the price you get with a 2 year contract). 
And if you pay tax when importing to ireland, the device will probably cost you about the same.